# Lucid vesting demo

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, lucid

I'm running into the follow Lucid error from Week4 of Plutus pioneer program:

```
/workspace/code/Week04/lecture# deno run -A lucid-vesting.ts
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined to a BigInt
      keyDeposit: BigInt(result.key_deposit),
                  ^
    at BigInt (<anonymous>)
    at Blockfrost.getProtocolParameters (https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.10.6/src/provider/blockfrost.ts:39:19)
    at async Function.new (https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.10.6/src/lucid/lucid.ts:56:34)
    at async file:///workspace/code/Week04/lecture/lucid-vesting.ts:19:15
```

I tried updating the import to use the latest Lucid version, but it didn't help:

`from "https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.10.6/mod.ts"`

I'm not sure what these type errors mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result.key_deposit` is `undefined`, which means it is not set to a value (and not `null` either). `BigInt()` expects you to provide a valid integer number either as a number or a string. Therefore `BigInt()` throws an error when you provide `undefined` instead.

Check what happens in your code before this line to figure out why `result.key_deposit` doesn't contain a number.

See [BigInt coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#bigint_coercion) for more info on BigInt  errors.

One likely pitfall I can see is that you might not have replaced the [Blockfrost API key](https://blockfrost.io/):

```
// set blockfrost endpoint
const lucid = await Lucid.new(
  new Blockfrost(
    "https://cardano-preprod.blockfrost.io/api/v0",
    "insert you own api key here" // <-- REPLACE THIS WITH A REAL API KEY
  ),
  "Preprod"
);
```